# In Emacs (with AUCTeX), if i use <C-c '> to see errors, it copies the command <C-c %>

Tags: emacs, auctex, accents

I don't know why, but since recently my Emacs is behaving strangely.
As usual I compiled using <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to call LaTeX, then there were errors and it asked me to type (as usual) <kbd>C-c '</kbd>. but when I did it just commented out the whole paragraph, which is the same effect as <kbd>C-c %</kbd>.
<kbd>C-c %</kbd> still works the same and typing <kbd>'</kbd> produces the same letter, i.e., `'`. so I somehow have my doubts that it is related to the keyboard, but not out of the question, of course.
I can't recall having done any setting changes or changes to my setup since the last time it worked perfectly, but i am not completely sure.

I'm running Emacs under Ubuntu, `Latex/MP Fly Ref` are the automatically hooked modes.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: To see errors you have to use C-c ` (backtick), not `C-c '`.  `C-h k C-c '` explains you what's going on: C-c ' runs the command TeX-comment-or-uncomment-paragraph, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `tex.el'.

It is bound to C-c %, C-c ', <menu-bar> <LaTeX> <Comment or Uncomment
Paragraph>.

Comment: thank you very much! that did the whole trick...
yday i was also trying the backtick command, but that did also create some strange outcome and so i was lost in how to check errors.
do not know why my memory told me that i usually used C-c ' ....
now it works just perfectly :)

Comment: @giordano Sounds like an answer :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred Done `:-)`.

Answer (score 5):

To see errors you have to use <kbd>C-c `</kbd> ([backtick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick)), not <kbd>C-c '</kbd>. <kbd>C-h k C-c '</kbd> (<kbd>C-h k</kbd> is bound to [`describe-key`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Help.html) ) explains you what's going on:

```
C-c ' runs the command TeX-comment-or-uncomment-paragraph, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `tex.el'.

It is bound to C-c %, C-c ', <menu-bar> <LaTeX> <Comment or Uncomment
Paragraph>.

(TeX-comment-or-uncomment-paragraph)

Comment or uncomment current paragraph.
```

You can see the other key bindings for `TeX-next-error` with <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `TeX-next-error` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

```
TeX-next-error is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
`tex-buf.el'.

It is bound to C-c `, C-x `, M-g n, M-g M-n.

(TeX-next-error REPARSE)

Find the next error in the TeX output buffer.
With C-u prefix, start from the beginning of the errors.
```